# Getting Multiple Data using Text field + Jbutton from SQL Server to Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Good day, just wanna ask. I have a Java GUI where I want to add multiple data from SQL server to my Jtable. The flow here is that I would want to use the text field as search field where I will add the info for searching and use the Jbutton to perform the search action then it will give/show me the data to my Jtable. Actually the code is running however some of the data like the 1st data added to my SQL serve and from data id 7 and and up are not showing. How would I fix this and show multiple data with same order ID form SQL server?
Thank you!!

```
       try {
            String query = "select * from `sales_product` where order_id = ?";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, txsearch.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    String prodname = rs.getString("prodname");
                    String price = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("price"));
                    String qty = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("qty"));
                    String total = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("total"));

                    model = (DefaultTableModel) datatable.getModel();

                    model.addRow(new Object[]{
                        prodname,
                        price,
                        qty,
                        total
                    });
                        int sum = 0;

                    for (int a = 0; a < datatable.getRowCount(); a++) {
                        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(datatable.getValueAt(a, 3).toString());
                    }

                    Ltotal.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                    }   
                }
            
                else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No order found!");
                txsearch.setText("");
            }
            
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(milktea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rs.next()) {
    while(rs.next()) {
```

No need for the `if (rs.next())` statement. That is causing you to skip the first row of data in the `ResultSet`.

All you need is the `while (rs.next())` statement to create the loop to read all rows in the `ResultSet`.